# How to use an image as texture on top of the Principled BSDF?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, transparency

I'm trying to create a node setup that allows me to use a Principled BSDF for the yellow lego plastic, but also use a .png with alpha for the face.

I can't figure out how to make that work, so my work around is to use an image texture with the face and a yellow background, as seen below.
[image]

But I'd rather use the Principled shader to control color.  Below is something I've tried unsuccessfully.
[image]

Can anyone suggest a node setup that'll allow me to use the .png WITH a Principled BSDF?